# How to load csv into R and be able to use it within a function

Tags: r, csv

I am getting this error every time I try to load in and use a csv file with a function (load_mix_data) I cannot figure out what the issue is. I can see the file in R studio, but when I try to use the function, I get the error.

"Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
'file' must be a character string or connection"

```
file_path <- "~/Desktop/ADFG Black Bear Stable Isotope/SI_Sp.csv"
mix.filename <- read.table(file_path, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"")

source.filename <- read.csv("Sources1_5_2021.csv")
discr.filename <- read.csv("DV_SIDER_omnivore.csv")

n.mod <-10

mix <- vector("list", n.mod)
#Define each model, note the factor or continuous effect

mix[[1]] <- load_mix_data(filename=mix.filename,
                          iso_names=c("C","N"),
                          factors=c(NULL),
                          fac_random=c(NULL),
                          fac_nested=c(NULL),
                          cont_effects=c(NULL))


head(mix.filename)
```

```
  sample sex age class season month year bait dayshunt skullen skulwid lengthWidth
1     93   M   2     J      S     5 2016  Yes        1  9.9375  4.8750     14.8125
2    112   M   7     A      S     5 2016   No        2 11.3125  6.5000     17.8125
3    109   M   7     A      S     5 2016   No        4 11.5625  6.1250     17.6875
4    180   M   5     A      S     5 2016  Yes        2 10.1875  5.6250     15.8125
5    226   F   3    SA      S     5 2017  Yes        2  9.7500  5.5625     15.3125
6    208   M  11     A      S     5 2016  Yes        1 12.2500  7.0625     19.3125
        C    N
1 -22.214 6.59
2 -20.284 5.94
3 -23.864 5.04
4 -22.964 5.42
5 -25.572 5.54
6 -23.454 7.03
```

Comment: This is the exact code you are running? Which line specifically gives you the error?

Comment: In windows, tilde (`~`) points at whatever `R_USER` is set to in your environment variables.  By default that's `C:/Users/[username]/Documents` not `C:/Users/[username]`

Comment: The load_mix_data function is where I get the error

Answer (score 1):

OP forgot to mention where is `load_mix_data` from and I assume it's from `MixSIAR` from a quick search on CRAN. the problem is that `mix.filename` is actually not the filename needed since `mix.filename` is a dataframe as an output saved from `read.table()` . the one needed for the function is the string containing the link directory to the file and in your code it's `file_path`. So it should actually be

`mix[[1]] <- load_mix_data(filename=file_path,...)`

Comment: Wouldn't it be the just as fun `Users/elleryvincent/Documents/Desktop/ADFG Black Bear Stable Isotope/SI_Sp.csv`?  the tilde uses the `R_USER` environmental variable, not the working directory.

Comment: oh thanks, @PaulStaffordAllen I didn't know that. I just tested it using `dirname("~")` after changing current working directory. By the way, I'm not sure about the website policy, do I add your comment (about the tilde) to improve my answer? I'm a bit confused about how to respond to comments that contain further/better/correct information than the answer itself.

Comment: I think it's good practice to edit it in - people can always review the edit history if needed.

Comment: Hi, yes, I have no probelm loading the file in general, I will take the setwd out to make this more clear. The issue is running the function load_mix_data, that is where I get the error.